# Problems with PATH variable when installing the GPU version of tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow, path, miniconda

I am currently working on installing the gpu version of tensorflow onto my computer; however, I am experiencing several difficulties. My initial problem was a relatively common problem where Tensorflow was not able to find the CUDA libraries during installation, and I found a very useful post here on StackOverflow that mentioned that by changing the 'CUDA_PATH' environment variable on my computer and adding the 'bin' folder to said variable's path, Tensorflow should be able to find the CUDA libraries.

This didn't work for me, and so I changed the name of the environment variable 'CUDA_PATH' to simply be 'PATH', since that was the environment variable name that was shown on the post I followed.

It didn't work either so I changed it back. Now, everytime I open RStudio, the following error message appears:

```
Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(conda, c("run", in_env, run_args, shQuote(cmd), args),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/maria/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" run --prefix "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate" --no-capture-output "python" -c "import os; print(os.environ['PATH'])"' had status 1
```

I have tried uninstalling R, Rtools, Rstudio, miniconda and all my Nvidia GPU drivers, as well as CUDA and CUDANN. I then have re-downloaded every programme, and the error still appears whenever I start a session in Rstudio (before I can even do anything remotely related to tensorflow or before I even use R in any way).

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate some help with this issue.
Thanks :)

P.S.: Please find below a screenshot of my RStudio upon opening the programme.

[image]

Comment: What is the value of *new_path*? And where does the call to *sys.setenv* come from? Did you add it in `$HOME/.Rprofile`?